# Add Shipping Charge based on Category in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping

I want my customer to charge different shipping amount if their order contains any item from specific products.

For e.g If the order contains any item from category A, B or C then they should be charged  £25 + VAT rolled, rather than the standard £14.50 + VAT rolled:

How can i do that?
i am using Webshop apps shipping table rate matrix module.

Comment: Which  shipping you using? mean which delivery method you are setting from magento admin?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have no experience with that module, so unsure of any config changes you could apply to implement this logic.

You could probably make this customisation yourself programmatically by creating an after plugin on `\WebShopApps\MatrixRate\Model\Carrier::getRates` method? Or maybe rewriting that method with a class preference?

This method takes in your rate request (including cart items, addresses etc) and returns the rates loaded from the database. You could apply this logic to the rates returned from the database here?